# Return behavior for recursion in Ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion

I was working on a simple recursive method to implement Euclid's algorithm in Ruby, and find myself stuck figuring out how to return the desired value once the base case is reached. Here's what I have to far:

```
def euclid_alg(larger,smaller)
  if larger % smaller == 0 && smaller != 1
    return smaller
  else
    puts 'calling self'
    euclid_alg(smaller, (larger % smaller))
    puts 'executed section after call'
  end
  puts "made it here #{smaller} #{larger}"
  nil
end
puts euclid_alg(100,15)
```

And the output:

```
calling self
calling self
executed section after call
made it here 10 15
executed section after call
made it here 15 100
```

Note there is no output from "puts euclid_alg(100,15)" which I was expecting to return the greatest common divisor of 100 and 15, 5.

In order to troubleshoot, I replaced the `return smaller` on line 3 with `puts smaller`. The new output was:

```
calling self
calling self
5
made it here 5 10
executed section after call
made it here 10 15
executed section after call
made it here 15 100
```

The addition of the "made it here 5 10" to the console output makes it clear that the return statement is breaking out of the function call, but not "parent calls."

How can I do recursion better?

Comment: Readers: from the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), the Euclidean algorithm "is an efficient method for computing the greatest common divisor (GCD) of two numbers, the largest number that divides both of them without leaving a remainder."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is just fine.  You are simply missing a return.  Note:

```
def euclid_alg(larger,smaller)
  if larger % smaller == 0 && smaller != 1
    return smaller
  else
    puts 'calling self'
    return euclid_alg(smaller, (larger % smaller)) # <<<<<  Return here
    puts 'executed section after call'
  end
  puts "made it here #{smaller} #{larger}"
  nil
end
puts euclid_alg(100,15)
```